# need help with Field Managers Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I keep getting an IllegalArgumentException and nothing shows on the BlackBerry simulator when I run this code.  What could be wrong with it?

```
 public MyScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen and add the weather icons      
        setTitle("PixWeather");

        cityField = new LabelField("Queensland", Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        tempField = new LabelField("17", Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

        condField = new LabelField("sunny",Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

       weather_icon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("sun_icon.png");
        bitmapField = new BitmapField(weather_icon, Field.FIELD_LEFT);

        VerticalFieldManager vfield = new VerticalFieldManager();


        HorizontalFieldManager hfield1 = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfield1.add(cityField);
        hfield1.add(tempField);

        HorizontalFieldManager hfield2 = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfield2.add(bitmapField);
        hfield2.add(condField);

        vfield.add(hfield1);
        vfield.add(hfield2);

    }
```

Comment: Step 1 is to figure out where the IllegalArgumentException is thrown.  Do some debugging to figure that out, and then update this question with your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IllegalArgumentException could be unrelated, but nothing is showing up on your screen because you didn't add anything to your screen.

You need to add the vfield to the screen itself. Add the following line:

```
add(vfield);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i tried what you suggested, but i keep getting a message that source file not found and i should open debug perspective window. don't know whats wrong. Sorry to bother, but quite new to Blackberry Deevelopment.

Comment: I think you should either try another simulator, or do a wipe of the data on the simulator before launching (file menu in the JDE). You need to get rid of whatever other app is throwing that exception. Getting an exception in code that you don't have access isn't a good situation to be in when you're trying to do proper dev. Also, go into the debug menu and uncheck anything that says you should break into debug mode on stupid things, like memory allocations.